# Array1 is added into Array2 then Array1 is cleared and suddenly disappears from Array2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays

I have this curious thinf happening here where tempArray is supposed to be added to the masterArray each time the if statement occurs. (The if statement works perfectly and gets triggered when it should.)

I also need to clear the temp array each time it does.

My final result should then be a masterarray which contains each array it has added.(meaning all the temp arrays that I have added throughout the for loop)

Instead, it only keeps adding the tempArray to the MasterArray at index 0 every single time.

**Code:**

```
- (void)alpabetize:(NSArray *)arr {

self.tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.masterArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i<[arr count]; i++) {

    NSString *currentString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[arr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"first_name"] substringToIndex:1]];
    NSString *nextString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[arr objectAtIndex:(i+1)] valueForKey:@"first_name"] substringToIndex:1]];

    [self.tempArray addObject:[arr objectAtIndex:i]];

    if (![currentString isEqualToString:nextString]) {

    [self.masterArray addObject:tempArray];
    [self.tempArray removeAllObjects];

    }

}

}
```

If you remove all objects from the original array previously added to some other array. Does this also clear the other array? This makes no sense to me. There must be something wrong in my code. Can somebody help me spot my error?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You should never call `[self.tempArray release];` You never release the result of a method call (`-tempArray` in this case). I'm surprised that this isn't crashing. I would also expect this to crash every time at the end of the loop. See Inder's answer for why your having the specific issue.

Comment: @RobNapier Thanks for the comment! It works now with Inders answer. The release part was just something I put in there just for the hell of it after 2h of debugging. Im amazed it didnt crash either. Since it gave me the same end result, I forgot to remove that part before posting it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
[self.masterArray addObject:[tempArray copy]]; // retained copy of array
```

or

```
[self.masterArray addObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:tempArray]]; // auto released copy of array
```

instead of

```
[self.masterArray addObject:tempArray];
```

In your code you are adding the reference of the same array which you are clearing in next statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
[self.masterArray addObjectsFromArray:tempArray];
[tempArray removeAllObjects];
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to release the self.tempArray inside the loop? Once it enters your IF-condition the the array will be nil and you'll have no use of it unless you call the this method again. Try releasing the self.tempArray after the for loop.